# Adding custom method to Object.prototype in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```js
Object.prototype.custom = function() {
    return this
}
```

It works just fine in JavaScript, but when I put it in TypeScript, I get this error:

```
Property 'custom' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)
```

How can I bypass or solve this complaint?

Comment: Just **don't add anything to global prototypes**. (Don't do that in JS either!) Please, at least don't add anything to `Object.prototype`! Especially, don't make it enumerable!!! (Your code will add that property to *every single object in existence*, not even only the ones you manually create, and will even show up as a key in `for..in` loops, which is bad. Like, ***very bad***. Doing that in your project is shooting yourself in the foot. Doing that in a library is shooting *everyone* in the foot.)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of the experiment (not advised in production, IMO), you could either `ignore` it or extend `Object` (aka augmentation)

```
// @ts-ignore
Object.prototype.custom = function() {
    return this
}

interface Object {
  custom2(): Object;
}

Object.prototype.custom2 = function() {
    return this
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEBcGcFoEsDmA7A9gJwKYCgDyAjAK0wGNIA6AB3VUloE9LNySBXaOgW1AF5QAzVsjLxUyABQBKUAG9soBaCyRW6ZKEgALeNGwBfbNnjJImdPwCGJTKALEys+aDYdUnAExSAXLaKlIANz6hnb+VDR0kIzMLlzuvAJCImJSjopKmCpqGtq6ekA)

Comment: Might want to link to docs on [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) as well as possibly talking about [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) if the code is in a module.  But yeah, I agree that this is a BAD IDEA.